# Route doesn't work when typing directly on the browser

Tags: aurelia

Why the Aurelia route doesn't work when we type it directly on the browser? I have configured the Aurelia to remove the "#" from the URL. It works well when clicking on the links in the website, but when I try to type the URL directly on the browser, it only works with "#".

That's the situation:

**With website links**

localhost/#/route -> works

localhost/route  -> works

**Typing on the browser**

localhost/#/route -> works

localhost/route  -> doesn't work

That's my configuration:

```
configureRouter(config, router){
        config.title = 'Dreampper';
        router.baseUrl = "/";
        config.options.pushState = true;

        var navStrat = (instruction) => {
            instruction.config.moduleId = instruction.fragment
            instruction.config.href = instruction.fragment
        }

        config.map([
          { route: 'login', moduleId: './components/account/login', name: 'login', nav: true},
          { route: 'register', moduleId: './components/account/register', name: 'register'},
          { route: '', moduleId: './components/timeline/timeline', name: 'timeline', title: 'Timeline' },
          { route: 'welcome', moduleId: './components/account/welcome', name: 'welcome' },
          { route: ':username', moduleId: './components/profile/profile', name: 'profile', nav: false }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
```

I have the `<base href="/">` on the index.html.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

PushState navigation requires server-side configuration. You must configure your server appropriately. See the second yellow box at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7